# How do I initialize an instance variable when the object is created in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, constructor

In C++ I would do this in the constructor, but on Objective C I do not know how I am supposed to initialize it.

For example I have a member variable that has to be a dictionary and I want to initialize this dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you use the `init` method. For example:

```
Myclass *anInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

Some classes have specialized initializers that will take parameters. A classic example is any UIViewController subclass that you implement. Does this look familiar?

```
MyUIViewController *viewController = [[MyUIViewController alloc] initWithNibNamed: @"MyUIViewController" bundle: nil];
```

Notice the `initWithNibNamed` bit. You can write custom initializer like that as well. I suggest reading code that others wrote. Look for the initializer and try to understand how it was written/"set up".

To make a dictionary, you can use `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`. Those have several initializers. You can use `initWithObjects:` and then pass in a bunch of objects to store in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

When you say initialize the dictionary, I am assuming you just want to allocate memory for it.  If so you can do the following sample:

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _privateDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:40];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read - [The Objective-C Programming Language: Allocating and Initializing Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#)